# jquery drop drag into a section that i have just created on the fly doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have a form builder app where i can click to add a new field and also click to add whole sections that contain fields / lines.   I can also drap and drop to re-order the fields in a section and the sections them selves and also drap fields between sections.

Problem is that when i clone a section and then try to drag and drop a field into it from another existing section it doesnt drop untill i save the form and then drag into the new section.

I use .clone() to clone a section then insertAfter() to add the new section, then i use jqueryui drag and drop and between sections and jqueryui sortable to sort.

It seems when i add a new section its not being added to the dom so i cant drop into it ??

any help please??

thanks
rick

Comment: Could you paste some code? It dosen't look like they have a refresh method or something, and dosent you live - which means elements added after loading dosent get affected. You could proberly reload the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQUery UI dropable / dragable uses bind, which load all existing elements, but dosent listen to new elements added after the create method.

Could you try to use the destroy functionm and then recreate the widgets to see if it helps (also explains why it works on page refresh).

You could also bind  it to LIVE, which then also bind new elements. But it might have some drawbacks like editing the plugin code and so on.